# Applying Angular-JS filter on translated sentences

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

So I use a [filter](http://angular-translate.github.io/) to i18n my app.

In this way i have a couple of JSON that maps the tokens. Something like:

```
 {
    TOKEN_1 : word,
    TOKEN_2 : Something Cool!
 }
```

Now I'm doing a table in witch I want to have a text filter, where the user fills the input and I show him all the info where the string that was wrote appears.

For this I'm using the `filter:searchText` from [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).
The problem is that my filter is applying on the JSON and not on its location mapping.

Summing up : I want to search for "Something Cool" but my filter only shows something if i search for "TOKEN_2"

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="section-head">
    <input type="text" id="filter" ng-model="searchText" />
</div><!-- /.section-head -->

<div class="section-body">
    <div ng-repeat="lot in lotList | filter:searchText>
         {{lot.status | translate}}
     </div>
</div>
```

**My Ctrl**

```
app.controller('Ctrl',function Ctrl($scope){
  $scope.searchText = "";
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Comment: @Michelem edited with some code

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a fiddle or plunker would be easier. However, this could help you:

```
| filter: { TOKEN_1: searchText }
```

You could also create your own filters.

Here is a fiddle with an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qh6t61f8/1/